# Meteorjs Global Variables are undefined in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, localhost, global-variables, undefined

I have a Meteor application which of course have some Global variables such as collections or some functions that I want to use in both server and client side. The problem is after the new version of Chrome all of the Global variables are undefined on client side, however it works fine on other browsers such as IE, Firefox etc. Moreover, what is strange is it works fine on chrome when I run the application locally but the problem arises just when I deploy the application on the server.

Could someone help regarding this issue?

Comment: can you give a bit mor background information, which chrome version exactly? which os you are running on? some code example or is for instance the "Meteor" variable not defined as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use `require`.

```
> require("/path/to/collection.js").MyCollection.findOne();
```